# An interesting identity for Dirichlet-like integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function, fresnel-integrals

I was looking for a proof of the following identity

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(x^{a})dx = \Gamma\left(1 + \frac{1}{a}\right) \cdot \sin\left(\frac {\pi}{2a}\right)$$

I have tried using the Legendre duplication formula and Euler's reflection formula, but both of them have been ineffectual. Would appreciate some help.

Motivation : Fresnel integrals and integrals of the form $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt [a] {x}}dx.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of the [Mellin transform](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MellinTransform.html) this integral becomes straightforward.  Substitute $x^a=t$:

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(x^{a}) \; \mathrm{d}x  = \frac{1}{a} \int_0^{\infty} t^{\frac{1}{a}-1} \sin(t) \; \mathrm{d}t 
$$
Which is the Mellin transform of $\sin(t)$ where $z=\frac{1}{a}$.  Therefore, the original integral equals
$$\frac{1}{a} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{a}\right) \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2a}\right)}=\boxed{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right) \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2a}\right)}}$$
Note that this result holds for $-1 < \Re \big[ \frac{1}{a} \big] <1$.